# Showing sequence of integrals is Cauchy

Tags: real-analysis

I have a question regarding the following sequence of integrals. Basically I think my estimation is very whacked, so I want to see where exactly I made an error. For a real number $x$, let $(*x)$ denote the ceiling function (i.e least integer greater than $x$). Define a sequence of integrals \begin{equation}p_n=\int_{1/2}^{n+1/2} \frac{\cos(x)}{x}d(*x)\end{equation}
We would like to show that $(p_n)$ is a convergent sequence in the real numbers. My strategy is of course to show that this is Cauchy. Let $m>n$ be positive integers. Then,
\begin{equation}p_n-p_m=\int_{n+1/2}^{m+1/2} \frac{\cos(x)}{x}d(*x)\leq \int_{n+1/2}^{m+1/2} \frac{1}{x}d(*x)\end{equation}
But then we using exercise 6.17 from baby Rudin, we have
\begin{equation}\int_{n+1/2}^{m+1/2} \frac{1}{x}d(*x)= \frac{m+1}{m+1/2}-\frac{n+1}{n+1/2}+\int_{n+1/2}^{m+1/2}\frac{1}{x^2}(*x) dx\end{equation}
Now the first two terms will each go to 1 as $m,n\to \infty$, so the difference becomes $1-1=0$. We just need to see that the third term goes to $0$ as $m,n\to \infty$. Now
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\int_{n+1/2}^{m+1/2}\frac{1}{x^2}(*x) dx=&(\int_{n+1/2}^{n+1}+\int_{n+1}^{n+2}+...+\int_{m}^{m+1/2})\frac{1}{x^2}(*x)dx\\
=&(n+1)(\frac{1}{n+1/2}-\frac{1}{n+1})+(n+2)(\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+2})+...+m(\frac{1}{m-1}+\frac{1}{m})+(m+1)(\frac{1}{m}-\frac{1}{m+1/2})\\
=&(\frac{n+1}{n+1/2}-1)+(\frac{n+2}{n+1}-1)+...+(\frac{m}{m-1}-1)+(\frac{m+1}{m}-\frac{m+1}{m+1/2})\\
\to& 0+0+...+0.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
It's mainly that last step that I'm very suspicious of. I'm not sure I'm even allowed to do that. If someone could help me out here that would be great.

Comment: The last step *is* wacky. If each term is small but the number of terms is large, then the sum need not be small. Here $m$ can be arbitrarily larger than $n$. For example $\frac{1}{n}+\cdots+\frac{1}{m}$ would also go to zero by the same argument, but it doesn't.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification. This is sort of the issue that I was expecting since I know the harmonic series is not Cauchy, but I just wanted to be sure. Any advice on a better estimation strategy for this sequence?

Comment: I actually ended up figuring it out. I used a similar strategy with the formula from the book, but by keeping the cosine factor, I was able to get an estimate involving the tail end of the convergent series $\sum\cos(n)/n$, which of course goes to 0.

Comment: If you examine the definition of Riemann-Schwarz integral, it is easy to show that $\forall n \in \Bbb Z, \int_{n-1/2}^{n+1/2} f(x)\,d(*x) = f(n)$. hence $$p_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac {\cos k}k$$.